# 'Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.Models.FormModel' vs. 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel'

Tags: sitecore

I'm getting the following error when trying to add an MVC form to a placeholder in a View:

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.Models.FormModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel'.

The view that contains the placeholder is setting the model to RenderingModel, so is it possible to add that MVC form to that view or do I need to create a new view/layout that doesn't explicitly set the model?

Comment: When you say MVC Form, I assume you are using the WFFM module? Have you correctly set the Datasource on the MVC Form control which you have added, and is it pointing to an item of template type `/sitecore/templates/Web Forms for Marketers/Form`?

Comment: I think you've set the datasource to the form on the container view rendering, rather than adding the form to the placeholder and setting it on the form itself.

Comment: Yes, WFFM 2.4. And yes, my datasource item has the appropriate template. But every time I try to add the one I created to a page it wants to make a copy of it. Either way, the template is the same.

Comment: And if you delete just the form does the error disappear?